# How to clear all debugging breakpoints in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can one clear all debugging breakpoints in Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VSCode top bar : Run > Remove All Breakpoints.

Comment: Are you aware of a keyboard shortcut to achieve the same?

Comment: file >pereference > keyboard shortcuts then search for 'removeAllBreakpoints' then you can add your own shortcut